# how to make my test return error and the view method

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I'm developing a system for to study OOJS. And I want to view the infos of book, I couldn't make my test work ... I crashed this part.

My test needs to check if the title of the book is the same as the one "registered" and call the method toView do class Book.

class Book

```
export default class Book{
    constructor(title, summary){
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
    }
    set title(title){
        if (isEmpty(title) || isNull(title))
        throw new Error(`can't be empty`);
      this._title = title;
    }
    set summary(summary){
        if(isEmpty(summary) || isNull(summary))
            throw new Error(`can't be empty`);
        this._summary = summary;
    }
    get title(){
        return this._title;
    }

    toView(){
        return `
            Title: ${this._title}\n
            Summary: ${this._summary}\n`
    }
}
}
```

class book dao

```
import Book from "../models/Book.js";
import {isEmpty, maxLength} from '../validate.js'
import ValidateErrors from "../validateErrors.js";

export default class BookDAO {
  constructor() {
    this._list = [];
  }
  hasTitle(book) {
    return this._list.some((b) => b.title === book.title);
  }

  validationBook(book) {
    const validate = new ValidateErrors();

    if (!(book instanceof Book)) {
      throw new Error(`The object is not a book`);
    }
    if (this.hasTitle(book)) {
      validate.addError(
        new Error(`There is already a book registration with that title!`)
      );
    }
    }
    return validate;
  }

  add(book) {
    const validatedBook = this.validationBook(book);
    if (validatedBook.hasErrors()) {
      throw validatedBook.errors;
    }
    this._list.push(book);
  }

  render(title){
    const book = this.hasTitle(title);

    if(!book){
      throw new Error ("was not found");
  }
    return book.toView();
}
}
```

class test book

```
import BookDAO from '../dao/Book.js'
import Book from '../models/Book.js'

try{
    const bookDAO = new BookDAO();
    const book = new Book("Design UX/UI","Summary");
      bookDAO.add(book);
      bookDAO.render("Design");

      console.log({book});    
} catch(err){  
    console.log(err)   
}
```

my test fails to return the error of searching for an unregistered book

thanks for any help!